# excel2img gives error "Exception: Failed locating range rez-2!A1:A3"

Tags: python, excel

if my sheet contains `-` symbol - its raise error, but when i rename it to `rez2` - all works

```
export_img("test2.xlsx", "rez.png", "rez-2","rez-2!A1:A3") #"Exception: Failed locating range rez-2!A1:A3"
```

Problem with this code in lib

```
rng = excel.workbook.Application.Range(_range)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that `export_img` is a function or subroutine and "text2.xlsx", "rez.png", "rez-2", "rez-2!A1:A3" are the parameters being passed through.

Try this:

```
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rez-2").Range("A1:A3")
```